# Cassandra CQL token function for pagination

Tags: database, cassandra, token, cql3

I am new to CQL and  trying to add pagination support for my tables defined in cassandra as shown below -

```
cqlsh:dev> create table emp4 (empid uuid , year varchar , month varchar , day varchar, primary key((year, month, day), empid));
cqlsh:dev> insert into emp4 (empid, year, month, day) values (08f823ac-4dd2-11e5-8ad6-0c4de9ac7563,'2014','03','19');
cqlsh:dev> insert into emp4 (empid, year, month, day) values (08f823ac-4dd2-11e5-8ad6-0c4de9ac7562,'2016','03','19');

cqlsh:dev> select * from emp4;

 year | month | day | empid
------+-------+-----+--------------------------------------
 2016 |    03 |  19 | 08f823ac-4dd2-11e5-8ad6-0c4de9ac7562
 2015 |    03 |  19 | 08f823ac-4dd2-11e5-8ad6-0c4de9ac756f
 2014 |    03 |  19 | 08f823ac-4dd2-11e5-8ad6-0c4de9ac7563

When I try to execute a query to fetch the records based on the the following comparison, the statement seems to be incomplete as show below - 

cqlsh:dev> select * from emp4 where token(year, month, day, empid) > token('2014','04',28',08f823ac-4dd2-11e5-8ad6-0c4de9ac7563) LIMIT 1;
       ... ;
       ...
```

I am trying to fetch records which have year,month, day greater than a specific value and also a given uuid. I think I am executing the query in the wrong way. Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, inputs that you send to the `token()` function must match your *partition* key...*not* your complete primary key:

Secondly, the order of your partition values is not necessarily the same as the tokens generated for them.  Look what happens when I insert three more rows, and the query using the `token` function:

```
 system.token(year, month, day) | year | month | day | empid
--------------------------------+------+-------+-----+--------------------------------------
           -8209483605981607433 | 2016 |    03 |  19 | 08f823ac-4dd2-11e5-8ad6-0c4de9ac7562
           -6378102587642519893 | 2015 |    03 |  19 | 08f823ac-4dd2-11e5-8ad6-0c4de9ac7562
           -5253110411337677325 | 2013 |    03 |  19 | 08f823ac-4dd2-11e5-8ad6-0c4de9ac7562
           -3665221797724106443 | 2011 |    03 |  19 | 08f823ac-4dd2-11e5-8ad6-0c4de9ac7562
           -2421035798234525153 | 2012 |    03 |  19 | 08f823ac-4dd2-11e5-8ad6-0c4de9ac7562
            -742508345287024993 | 2014 |    03 |  19 | 08f823ac-4dd2-11e5-8ad6-0c4de9ac7563

(6 rows)
```

As you can see, the rows are decidedly *not* in order by year.  And in this case your 2014 row has generated the *largest* token.  Therefore querying for rows with a token value larger than that year will yield nothing.  But, if I want to query for rows with a token year greater than 2013, it works:

```
SELECT token(year,month,day),year,month,day,empid FROM emp4 
  WHERE token(year,month,day) > token('2013','03','19');

 system.token(year, month, day) | year | month | day | empid
--------------------------------+------+-------+-----+--------------------------------------
           -3665221797724106443 | 2011 |    03 |  19 | 08f823ac-4dd2-11e5-8ad6-0c4de9ac7562
           -2421035798234525153 | 2012 |    03 |  19 | 08f823ac-4dd2-11e5-8ad6-0c4de9ac7562
            -742508345287024993 | 2014 |    03 |  19 | 08f823ac-4dd2-11e5-8ad6-0c4de9ac7563

(3 rows)
```

Also note that you will need to use dates of your existing rows to return results that are of more value to you.  After all, the token generated by `token('2014','04','28')` may not actually be greater than the token generated by `token('2014','03','19')`.