# Cassandra - Token pagination over bucket approach

Tags: database, cassandra, pagination, cql, cassandra-3.0

I am currently working on a chat and I would like to paginate the messages of a given thread. I am a Cassandra table which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
  ID uuid,
  ...
  CreatedAt timestamp,
  ...
  ThreadID varchar,
  Bucket int,
  ...,
  PRIMARY KEY ((ThreadID, Bucket, SentAt), ID)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ID DESC);
```

The approach is to have messages partitioned by ThreadID and by Bucket (so each partition gets maximum of 100k messages) and by SentAt date (to paginate). I also use the ID in my primary key in order to ORDER my message at insertion time. *If I am wrong, please correct me*

I got this approach from both of the following links:

- Discord Blog: https://blog.discordapp.com/how-discord-stores-billions-of-messages-7fa6ec7ee4c7
- SO Question: [Cassandra CQL token function for pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601280/cassandra-cql-token-function-for-pagination)

**(Disclaimer: the following code is reading only, nothing really developed yet)**

If I query using `SELECT token(ThreadID, Bucket, SentAt),... FROM Messages WHERE token(ThreadID, Bucket, SentAt) < token('5e139304b842595704c01da0', 3, '2020-01-06 21:00:23 +0000');`, what will be the final behavior?

- Will it work if I use UUID instead of BigInt as ID type?
- Is the fact to order messages by ID will actually make faster the reading part?
- Based on some rules, the Bucket value might be increased by 1. Will the token approach using `< token(..., 3, date)` will first compare the date (descending) then the bucket?

Thanks for your clarification!

## EDIT An example to make it clearer

```
id   | threadid | bucketid | sentat
-----+----------+----------+---------------------------------
xxxx |    A     |    1     | 2020-01-06 21:00:23 +0000
xxxx |    A     |    1     | 2020-01-06 21:22:21 +0000
xxxx |    A     |    1     | 2020-01-06 23:00:00 +0000
.... | .......  | ........ | .........................
xxxx |    A     |    2     | 2020-01-07 01:23:50 +0000
.... | .......  | ........ | .........................
.... | .......  | ........ | .........................
xxxA |    A     |    3     | 2020-01-07 18:30:49 +0000
xxxB |    A     |    3     | 2020-01-07 18:30:55 +0000
.... | .......  | ........ | .........................
```

Here is my table (abstracted of course). Every X messages, the BucketID gets increased (let say each ~100k new messages). My latest returned message is the message **xxxA**. From here, I want to paginate 10 more messages. Using the bucket ID would help me to only paginate over a partition of my table (Partition 3 for now). However, if I can't get messages, I need to reduce my BucketID while I am querying and try again.

So, would I need a double token approach for my WHERE clause? Because I need the token (ThreadID, BucketID) to be (A, 3) at first, but at the same time, I want to get the first 10 results before (older than) the given token (ThreadID, SentAt)(A, 2020-01-07 18:30:49 +0000)

Thanks!